# Can I get the mouse position with a different format

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to get the position of my mouse, but make it print just the coordinates like

```
1000, 1000
```

Not like

```
Point(x=1212, y=621)
```

My Code:

```
x = pyautogui.position()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
import pyautogui

x,y = pyautogui.position()
print(f"x:{x}, y:{y}")
```

Output:

```
x:479, y:441
```

If you don't want `x` and `y` to appear then you can use:

```
import pyautogui

x,y = pyautogui.position()
print(x, y)
```

Output:

```
479, 441
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print(x)
print(y)
```